# Performing Actions With Pairs in Arrays/Lists in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Sorry if the title's worded a bit weird but this is what I'm trying to get to.

Lets say you have an array of integers like this:

```cs
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

What would be the best way to use this array to return a new array but with the values of each pair summed together, so using the array above, it would return

```cs
{ 3, 7, 11, 15, 19 }
```

Obviously you can so something basic like

```cs
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var x = new List<int>();
for (int i=0;i<arr.Length;i+=2)
    x.Add(arr[i] + arr[i+1]);
```

But if you want to keep your code concise and/or work with different items, this doesn't really seem like the best option.

So is there any other/better way to do this? I was testing some ideas with Enumerable.Aggregate but couldn't come up with anything, please share ideas.

Comment: Small optimization: `var x = new List<int>(arr.Length / 2);`

Comment: Well the point isn't to optimize my example, it's to find a better alternative to my example.

Comment: This is perfectly readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue that your approach is perfectly fine, but for LINQ you can do some stuff with `Chunk`:

```cs
var x = arr
    .Chunk(2)
    .Where(c => c.Length == 2)
    .Select(c => c.Sum())
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code is readable and efficien; however, you can generalize your current solution a bit:

- Last array item(s) can well have no pair
- We can combine not only pairs, but three or four items etc.

If you are looking for such kind of code for

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

the modifiction of your solution can be:

```
const int size = 2;

int[] result = new int[arr.Length / size + Math.Sign(arr.Length % size)];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
  result[i / size] += arr[i];
```

For instance, if we set `size = 3;` then for we'll get `{ 6, 15, 24, 10 }` as the `result`. Note, that the last group is incomplete:

```
   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
   |     |  |     |  |     |  ||
      6        15       24    10
```

Comment: `Math.Sign(arr.Length % size)` is a clever way to add one extra item to the result array if there is a remainder in the division.